# Should we use smb or cifs to connect to a Linux NAS?

Tags: smb, nas, cifs

If it is a Linux NAS (WD EX2100 or EX4100), should we use

```
smb://MyCloud
```

or

```
cifs://MyCloud
```

to connect to it if for some reason, it doesn't show up at the side panel of Finder?

The above line is to be typed into

```
Finder -> Go -> Connect to Server
```

and for a Windows PC, I think it is to use `smb`. For an NAS, we can use either `smb` or `cifs` but which one should be used?

Comment: Can you type in the IP address of the Linux NAS?

Comment: I can use IP address but using a name is easier. (and the IP address can change)

Comment: `smb` is SMB v3 and is current technology, and `cifs` is SMB v1 with Microsoft extensions and is 1990s era (and *might* "fall back" (fall forward?) to `smb` SMB v3 anyway).

Answer (score 2):

CIFS is roughly the same as SMB version 1 (it's more complicated than that, but they're close enough for our purposes). Apple's implementations of SMB version 2 (introduced in OS X v10.9) and version 3 (OS X v10.10) were a bit buggy, at least at first. If you use an "smb://" URL in the connect dialog, it'll use the newest version that both the server and client support, and if you're *still* seeing weird behavior from that... then you can use "cifs://" to force it back to the old version 1 protocol, which might fix it (see e.g. [this ZDNet article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/mavericks-smb2-problem-and-fixes/), which also gives a way to force version 1 via the nsmb.conf file).

If you aren't having trouble with the newer version of the protocol, or you are but switching back to the old version doesn't help, then use "smb://" -- the newer versions of the protocol are significantly faster and generally better.